# Cambiar codigo de windows a linux

Tags: c++, linux

¿cómo puedo modificar este código a linux? 
necesito una alternativa a `#include<windows.h>` 
para realizar este codigo:

```
GetCursorPos(&cursor);
x = cursor.x;
y = cursor.y;

Sleep(2000)
SetCursorPos(x, y);

mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Dado que parece que estas usando un framework especifico, probablemente .Net?

Tienes que revisar que ese framework pueda compilar para plataformas linux.

QT por ejemplo es multiplataforma, .Net no lo es, ninguna de las librerias graficas son compatibles nada mas que para las distintas versiones de windows

Comment: Qt no permite hacer esa funcionalidad

Comment: @eyllanesc que funcionalidad? obtener la posicion de un cursor y setearla mas tarde? Una sencilla busqueda en StackOverflow te demostrará rapidamente lo contrario, podrias ser mas especifico?

Comment: Lo que señalo es que Qt no realiza dicha acción, si vas a mandar a la gente a SO que sentido tiene SOes.

Comment: [enlace](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcursor.html) Ahi puedes ver la especificación de que sí que tiene ambas funciones, Pos() y setPos()